# Sort Object.entries alphabetically by key

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say I have this:

```
for(let [k,v] of Object.entries({a:1,b:2}).sort((a,b) => b[0] - a[0])){
  console.log({k,v});
}
```

I always get this output:

```
{ k: 'a', v: 1 }
{ k: 'b', v: 2 }
```

even if I switch it to:

```
a[0] - b[0]
```

why can't I sort the keys alphabetically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost always better off with [localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare) when comparing strings. It gives you a lot more flexibility and options to deal with capitalization, international characters, and numbers. And it returns exactly what `sort()` wants:

```js
let arr = Object.entries({a:1,b:2})

arr.sort((a,b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0]))
console.log(arr)

arr.sort((a,b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]))
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: ah yes localCompare, the method with the name that makes no sense, what is localCompare supposed to mean? Why that name? lol, thanks tho

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman -- yeah it's a little opaque, but it takes a locales option that helps when different languages and alphabets sort things differently.

Comment: ah yes,  in French `b` might come before `a` in their alphabet, or what not

Answer (score 0):

nvm, my question makes no sense, there would be no obvious definition for subtraction for strings. This works though.

```
const sorter = (a,b) => b[0] > a[0] ? 1 :  (b[0] < a[0] ? -1 : 0);

const sorted = Object.entries({a:1,b:2}).sort(sorter);

for(let [k,v] of sorted){
  console.log({k,v});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort alphabetically, I recommend to use [String.localeCompare()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```js
let sortAsc = Object.entries({a:1, b:2}).sort((a, b) => a[0].localeCompare(b[0]));
let sortDesc = Object.entries({a:1, b:2}).sort((a,b) => b[0].localeCompare(a[0]));

console.log("Ascending:");
for(let [key, val] of sortAsc)
{
  console.log(key, val);
}

console.log("Descending:");
for(let [key, val] of sortDesc)
{
  console.log(key, val);
}
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another trick to accomplish this is using [fromEntries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to construct a new object from the sorted keys:

```js
const data = { b: 2, c: 3, a: 1 }
const sortedData = Object.fromEntries(
 Object.keys(data).sort().map(key => [key, data[key]])
)
console.log({ data, sortedData })
```